# How to restore mysql database if in the file is in .gz format and has different parts?

Tags: mysql

I need a little help here about restoring mysql database. My boss gave me a backup of database which is in the .gz format and it has 7 parts. I extract one od the .gz file but it doesn't include all the files like in .rar files if you extract the first .rar file it will extract the others and make it as a whole file. In my case after extracting the first .gz folder it only extracted the first one. It doesn't extract the others. How can I solve this problem guys? By the way after I extracting the first folder it has a file named 'db.backup.1' and when I opened this in a text editor it shows my database and the table. inside it. I also extracted the others and they are all the same. How can I merge them? Each file has a 125MB of data.

Answer (score 1):

- unzip them first
- merge them using the append cmd in linux

  cat file1 >> masterfile.sql
  and so on
   cat file2 >> masterfile.sql
- import your masterfile.sql in the desired database.

---

Windowzzzzz version
-form cmd line run

```
copy file1+file2+file3 targetfile
```

Comment: How can I do that using windows?